# Is It Possible to use <p:inputText> inside <p:confirmPopup>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans

Below is My DataTable

```
<p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{purchaseOrderDetailFileController.heldOrderList}" var="item"
                         selectionMode="single" selection="#{purchaseOrderDetailFileController.selected}"
                         paginator="true"
                         rowKey="#{item.id}" tableStyle="width:auto"
                         rows="10"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
                         >

                <p:column style="width:6rem">
                   
                    <p:commandButton value="Release" action="#{procurementModule.releaseHoldOrder(item)}" update="datalist, :growl" icon="pi pi-check" styleClass="rounded-button p-mr-2 p-mb-2">
                        <p:confirm type="popup" header="Release Password" message="Please Provide Release Password" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle"/>
                        
                    </p:commandButton>

                </p:column>

                <p:column >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Hold Code"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.purchaseOrderHeader.holdOrdersCode}"/>
                </p:column>
          </p:datatable>
```

Below is my p:confirmPopup

```
<p:confirmPopup global="true">

                <p:inputText id="password2" immediate="true" value="#{purchaseOrderDetailFileController.orderReleasePassword}">
                    
                </p:inputText><p:spacer/><p:spacer/><p:spacer/><p:spacer/><p:spacer/><p:spacer/>

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirm-popup-yes" >
                    
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:confirmPopup>
```

My method in my bean

```
public void releaseHoldOrder(PurchaseOrderDetailFile item) {
    try {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        PurchaseOrderDetailFileController purchaseOrderDetailFileController = (PurchaseOrderDetailFileController) elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "purchaseOrderDetailFileController");
      
      String password = purchaseOrderDetailFileController.getOrderReleasePassword();
    } catch(Exception e){
                       e.prinStackTrace();   
                       }
```

The problem is I am not getting the value from my input text in my bean?. what am i missing? Is there any possible way to pass a parameter from primefaces confirmPopup to my java bean.

Comment: I currently don't think this is possible.  The confirm popup I don't believe was designed to handle this scenario.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to customise the dialog box to apear like confirmPopup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a dialog in order for it to work properly.

```
<p:dialog id="confirm" header="Confirmation">  
    <h:form>  
        <p:inputText id="value" value="#{someBean.someProperty}" />  

        <!-- other form components --> 
    <f:facet name="footer">
    <p:commandButton type="button" value="No" styleClass="ui-button-flat p-mr-2" style="width: 6rem" />
    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Yes" style="width: 5rem" />
</f:facet>
    </h:form> 
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Yes I am currently using it, is there any way to customise the dialog box to apear line confirmPopup.